# How can I fix this cors error with cors module

Tags: node.js, npm, cors

I installed cors module and coded like below.

```
var express = require('express'),
    favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
    cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
}

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/logo.ico'));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('view');
});

app.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 80');
});
```

After this I turned on server and tried to access files on server by this code.

```
$.getJSON('https://server.domain/global.json', data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But It makes error.

I can access to js files but not json file.

[image]

What's the problem?

[+Edit]
I can get js files by

```
$.getScript('~/js/file.js');
```

But not by

```
$.get('~/js/file.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem with code below.

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Server in express don't allow you to access files directly.
if you want it to enable access files directly . you have  to do it like this

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

now you can access files in public folder directly like
if there is file data.json in public, you can access it by localhost:3000/data.json.
Hope this is answer of your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I'm not asking how to allow cors.
After I use cors module I can access to js and css files.
But json file makes error.
I also checked the question you linked.
It's not working :(

Comment: ok, i got it , i have updated the answer kindly check it , if its the answer to your query

Comment: Its nature of express, that it don't allow to access all files for security, so put data in a folder which you want to access directly and then make that folder stati accessable

Comment: I have line like that in my code and I can access the json file by url but not by console

Answer (score 0):

do you get the error after trying this:

```
app.get('/', cors(), (req, res) => {
    res.render('view');
});
```

and

```
$.getJSON('https://server.domain/global.json', cors(), data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Then I can't access to all types(.js / .css / .json / .txt) of files

Comment: to access them, you can use: `app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) { res.sendFile("http://localhost/index.htm"); res.end;  });`

Answer (score 0):

put the cors module as the first module that you load (use)

Comment: do you have a return type application/json?  try to get to file as non-JSON and JSON